# Data confusion caused by java concurrency

Tags: java, concurrency

Now two threads use readFileByBuffer to read text files. Thread A reads a text file that is all a, and thread B reads a text file that is all b, but sometimes checkLine detects data exceptions. I print the data and find that thread A reads strange data, such as aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb,This problem is difficult to reproduce, and I don't know how to troubleshoot it. If someone can give me some advice, I will thank him very much,My code is as follows:

```
`public boolean readFileByBuffer(Sting fileName){
 public boolean run(String fileName) {
         try(BufferedReader br =NewIoUtils.newBufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))){
             String readLine ;
             while((readLine = br.readLine()) != null){
                 checkLine(readLine);
         }
             return true;
         }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
             System.out.printf("con't fount file , fileName :%s ,异常\n",fileName );
         }catch(Exception e){
             System.out.printf("Reading file exception :fileName : %s ,异常\n",fileName );
         }
         return false;
     }
 
     public boolean checkLine(String line){
         if(StringUtils.isBlank(line))
         {
             log.error("The current line does not exist,projectCode:() ,batchId:()",projectCode,transBatchId);
             return false;
         }
         List<Sting>contents =CheckConfigUtils.getSplitLine(line);
         if (contents == null|| contents.size() < fieldCount)
         {
             log.error("Check that the number of fields is less than the configured number");
             return false;
         }
     }
 
 }`
```

This situation didn't occur until I upgraded the kernel to 4.19 when I used 3.10. I tried to upgrade openjdk, but it didn't work

Comment: using a lot of non-standard-Java classes (no lib/framework mention) and non-complete example makes helping hard - beset to include [mre] in question - it can be a problem with how threads work, what the libs are providing, how the output is printed, how data is being checked, ...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.